# insert multiple values in mysql in a nested select

Tags: mysql

I'm fairly new to sql. This might be basic. I have two tables one with groups and one with members, I want to link them up so that a third table contains id_group and id_member. The value MYGROUP is supplied during the import. I tried this:

```
insert ignore into member_group (id_group, id_member) 
values ( ( select id_group from group where group_name='MYGROUP' ) ,
( select id_member from member ) );
```

But I end up with one row in member_group containing a null value.

on it's own this yields 1 for example:

```
select id_group from group where group_name='MYGROUP';
+----------+
| id_group |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
```

on it's own this yields a list of id_members

```
mysql> select id_member from member;
+-----------+
| id_member |
+-----------+
|       123 |
|       456 |
|       789 |
```

I want member_group to then look like this

```
+-----------+----------+
| id_group  |id_member |
+-----------+----------+
|         1 |      123 |
|         1 |      456 |
|         1 |      789 |
```

How can I do this (without resorting to shell scripts, for loops and sed) ?

As requested,

```
mysql> select * from group;
+----------+------------------+
| id_group | group_name       |
+----------+------------------+
|        1 | vip-member       |
|        2 | standard-member  |


mysql> select * from member;
+-----------+----------+
| id_member | fullname |
+-----------+----------+
|       123 |      Bob |
|       456 |     Pete |
```

Which, if I could get it working, should look like below.

```
mysql> select * from member_group;
+------------------+----------+-----------+
| id_member_groups | id_group | id_member |
+------------------+----------+-----------+
|                1 |        1 |       123 |
|                2 |        1 |       456 |
|                3 |        1 |       789 |
|                4 |        2 |       123 |
|                5 |        2 |       789 |
```

id_group is supplied during the import phase. One batch of say 200 members, will be members of the same id_group. I was thinking about adding the group_id to a temporary table. But I'm a tad lost to be honest.

Comment: Does the members table have a column named id_group?

Comment: No. One member can be a member of many groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a cross join to achieve your goal.

```
insert ignore into member_group (id_group, id_member)
select member_group.id_group, member.id_member
from member_group 
cross join member
where group_name = 'MYGROUP';
```